# allow overflow on fixed positioned element

Tags: css

I have a fixed positioned element somewhere near bottom of my page. As there is more content to it than window height itself displays rest of it's been cut down.

I've tried adding `overflow:auto` to fix this issue and be capable of scrolling through fixed positioned element but no luck.

I suppose there might be a javascript solution near by but wondering if there is a css one as well.

Hope my question made sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to fix the height/width to get scrollbars, otherwise the `fixed` element expands out of view. Here's a little demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/mtjYR/). Basic outine:

HTML:

```
<div class = "fixed">
    Glee is awesome!<br/>
    ...
    Glee is awesome!<br/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: That's it! Many thanks! Can you explain why did you have to set html and body height as well? I've tried before setting some px height just to see if it would work but it didn't and it had to do with html and body height not being set.

Comment: @daniel.tosaba Because `html` and `body` by default resize to fit their content, so when you set `height: 100%;` in your fixed `div`, you get whatever height `body`/`html` has. To force it to be the full available window/screen, I used `html, body { height: 100%; }`.